# Position a normal button under appbar Android

Tags: java, android, button, appbar

I have a simple layout with an appbar and contents under it. I want to put a button anchored to the appbar like if it is a floating button.

I used attribute `layout_anchor` and it worked only in parts because the appbar cover the button top part.

The result looks like this:
[image: Screen]

Can anyone help me?

Comment: show what you did

Comment: I have attached a photo

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar issue in my app and adding a `android:marginTop` attribute to the root view of the layout seems to work just fine. Your can search for the exact value you should put there using trial and error, but you should be able to find the value you need in the values xml.